# connecting mongoose to every MVC file in mongoose

Tags: model-view-controller, mongodb, mongoose

Using MVC :

```
Node App Directory
   App.js
   Controllers
      UserController.js
      OtherController.js
   Models
      UserModel.js
      OtherModel.js
```

Since i used mongoose and mongodb for my dba, and the schema is considered 'model' in this case is the mongoose schema. Must i connect mongoose to each Controller and Model file each time i want to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to connect to mongoose in every controller/model file, you do it just once in `App.js`